# How to draw a line segment

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have used the tutorial or "recipe" here as a starting point in drawing objects in a canvas http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/drawing/draw_2d_graphics/

My question is: How can I draw a line segment, rather than drawing a shape such as an oval (in the example) or a rectangle (also similar process)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the answer soon after asking it, despite much attempt before.

The short answer is that you need to create a path, and then created a new PathShape using the path. Here's some code I added to the example provided by those at Xamarin which draws a 50 pixel long vertical line segment:

```
Path path = new Path ();
path.MoveTo(50, 0);
path.LineTo(50, 100);
_shape = new ShapeDrawable(new PathShape(path,100,100));
_shape.Paint.Set(paint);
```

Comment: You can also use the canvas.DrawLine method passing in points.